# NA matches NA, but is not equal to NA. Why?

Tags: r

In *R Language Definition*, `NA` values are briefly described, a portion of which says

> ... In particular, `FALSE & NA` is `FALSE`, `TRUE | NA` is `TRUE`. `NA` is not equal to
>   any other value or to itself; testing for `NA` is done using `is.na`. However, an `NA` value will match another `NA` value in `match`.

Regarding the statement  "`NA` **is not equal to
any other value or to itself**",

---

Updated: 
The question, revised again, is

**What is the reasoning, if any, behind** `NA` **matching** `NA` **in** `match`, **and nowhere else in the language?**

It doesn't make sense to me that a missing value, unknown by anyone (or it would not be missing), would match another missing value of the same type.  Since I posted this, I came across something in `example(match)` that provides some reasoning. Character coercion changes its type.  I can erase it completely if I like.

```
match(NA, NA)
# [1] 1
match(NA, NA_real_)
# [1] 1
match(NA_character_, NA_real_)
# [1] 1
match(paste(NA), NA)
# [1] NA
gsub("NA", "", NA)
# [1] NA
gsub("NA", "", paste(NA))
# [1] ""
is.na(NA)
# [1] TRUE
is.na(paste(NA))
# [1] FALSE
```

Apologies for stirring the pot, but some of the documentation is unclear about this.  It might boil down to the R parser/deparser and the fact that you can turn anything into a text character object in R.

---

Original Post:

Now referring to **"However, an** `NA` **value will match another** `NA` **value in** `match`."

If `NA` is it not equal to itself, why is it matched with itself in `match`?  and also in `identical`?  Is this done on purpose?

```
NA == NA  ## expecting TRUE
# [1] NA
NA != NA
# [1] NA
x <- NA
x == x
# [1] NA
match(NA, NA)
# [1] 1
identical(NA, NA)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(NA, NA)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking. You quote the portion of the spec that describes the behavior you observe, which seems to make clear that it's intentional; but then you ask "Is this done on purpose?", as though you weren't sure. Is there some reason for your doubt?

Comment: You should probably note that `identical(NA,NA_integer_)` returns false, so that part isn't really that surprising.

Comment: @joran, but isn't that just because a logical doesn't match an integer?

Comment: "just"? That's my point. There are 5 flavors of NA, for other atomic values. It's sensible to say that two of the same flavor are "identical". Remember that `identical` is intended for object identity in the strict programming sense, not "data equivalency" in a statistical sense.

Comment: ...as for `match`, that just seems like one of millions of at least partially subjective design decisions that happen when writing a language. The only real answer is probably that it made sense to whoever wrote it originally.

Comment: `?identical` has an argument `single.NA` which if set to `FALSE` will return FALSE. It tests by default if they're *conceptually* equal, as opposed to `==`. From `?==`, *"NAs are non-comparables even to themselves"*. I'm guessing `match` also has a *conceptual* touch to it, as it mentions: *"Exactly what matches what is to some extent a matter of definition."* No idea about `?all.equal` though. It doesn't even mention `NA` AFAICT.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a matter of convention.  There are good reasons for the way `==` works.  `NA` is a special value in R that is supposed to represent data that is missing and should be treated differently from the rest of data.  There are innumerable very subtle bugs that could come up if we started comparing missing values as if they were known or as if two missing values were equal to each other.

Think of `NA` as meaning "I don't know what's there".  The correct answer to `3 > NA` is obviously `NA` because we don't know if the missing value is larger than 3 or not.  Well, it's the same for `NA == NA`.  They are both missing values but the true values could be quite different, so the correct answer is "I don't know."

R doesn't know what you are doing in your analysis, so instead of potentially introducing bugs that would later end up being published and embarrassing you, it doesn't allow comparison operators to think NA is a value.

`match()` was written with a more specific purpose in mind: finding the indexes of matching values.  If you ask the question "Should I match 3 with NA", a reasonable answer is "no."  Different (and very useful) convention, and justified because R pretty much knows what you are trying to do when you invoke `match()`.  Now, should we match `NA` with `NA` for this purpose?  It could be argued.

Come to think of it, I suppose it is a a little odd that the authors of `match()` chose to allow `NA` to match to itself by default.  You can imagine cases where you might use `match()` to find `NA` rows in `table` along with other values, but it's dangerous.  You just have to be a bit more careful about knowing whether you have any NA values in x and only permitting them if you really wanted to.  You can change this behavior by specifying `incomparables=NA` when calling `match()`.

Comment: I found it very odd "that the authors of match() chose to allow NA to match to itself by default."

In what counter-intuitive scenario would you want this behavior? It would be a specific use-case and therefore should not have been default.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @farnsy's great answer, and to elaborate on the difference with `==` and `match`:

The key thing to consider is how these two functions (`==` and `match`) are used.

```
x == y
translation:  Is the value on the left the same value as the one on the right

match(x, table)
translation:  Is the value on the left found in the table on the right; 
              if so, return the index of the FIRST TIME that x appears in table
```

A common use case I often encounter is working with a set of IDs. Especially, when dealing with two different datasets that have been joined, I might be left with several NAs in one of my ID columns

However, not all NAs represent the same real life object.