# Removing NA observations with dplyr::filter()

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
    ~a, ~b, ~c,
    1, 2, 3, 
    1, NA, 3, 
    NA, 2, 3
)
```

I can remove all `NA` observations with `drop_na()`:

```
df %>% drop_na()
```

Or remove all `NA` observations in a single column (`a` for example):

```
df %>% drop_na(a)
```

Why can't I just use a regular `!=` filter pipe?

```
df %>% filter(a != NA)
```

Why do we have to use a special function from tidyr to remove NAs?

Comment: `price != "NA"` should work

Comment: because any comparison with `NA`, including `NA==NA`, will return `NA`

Comment: @Metrics: it's weird (to me) that that works. Can you explain why it does?

Comment: By the way, this has nothing specifically to do with `dplyr/filter`.

Comment: @Metrics, It doesn't.

Comment: related but not quite identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100974/na-matches-na-but-is-not-equal-to-na-why

Comment: @user3731467 I don't have the `diamonds` data, but on an example data, the suggestion by Metrics worked

Comment: This is also a good, related answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822426/r-dealing-with-true-false-na-and-nan

Comment: @BenBolker If you convert your comment to an answer I will accept. I did not realize that NAs behaved this way!

Comment: Which comment?  Looks to me like @MaratTalipov's comment might be the one you think is the answer?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From @Ben Bolker:

> [T]his has nothing specifically to do with dplyr::filter()

From @Marat Talipov:

> [A]ny comparison with NA, including NA==NA, will return NA

From a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100974/na-matches-na-but-is-not-equal-to-na-why) by @farnsy:

> The == operator does not treat NA's as you would expect it to.
>
> Think of NA as meaning "I don't know what's there". The correct answer
>   to 3 > NA is obviously NA because we don't know if the missing value
>   is larger than 3 or not. Well, it's the same for NA == NA. They are
>   both missing values but the true values could be quite different, so
>   the correct answer is "I don't know."
>
> R doesn't know what you are doing in your analysis, so instead of
>   potentially introducing bugs that would later end up being published
>   an embarrassing you, it doesn't allow comparison operators to think NA
>   is a value.

Answer (score 92):

For example:

you can use:

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(a))
```

to remove the NA in column a.

Comment: This takes far too long for large data (dataframe with 7.3m rows and 290 cols).. any faster methods?

Answer (score 45):

If someone is here in 2020, after making all the pipes, if u pipe `%>% na.exclude` will take away all the NAs in the pipe!

Answer (score 2):

I always use this and it is working perfectly

```
cool$day[cool$day==''] <- NA  
cool$day[is.na(cool$day)] <- "NA"

cool <- cool[!cool$day == "NA", ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using `complete.cases` in your `filter` to for example remove the NA in the column A. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(complete.cases(a))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     3
#> 2     1    NA     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>