# Ignore NA values in filtering with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as :

```
> tab
   Groups Species Value
1  Group1     Sp1     1
2  Group1     Sp1     4
3  Group1     Sp2    78
4  Group1     Sp3    NA
5  Group1     Sp4    NA
6  Group2     Sp2     3
7  Group2     Sp3     9
8  Group2     Sp4     8
9  Group3     Sp1     9
10 Group3     Sp3    10
11 Group3     Sp3   110
12 Group3     Sp3    14
```

and I'm trying to keep groups where values are < 80

I tried:

```
tab %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
    filter(all(Value < 80))
```

but I do not know how to ignore `NA values` in the filter.

Here I should get :

```
> tab
   Groups Species Value
1  Group1     Sp1     1
2  Group1     Sp1     4
3  Group1     Sp2    78
4  Group1     Sp3    NA
5  Group1     Sp4    NA
6  Group2     Sp2     3
7  Group2     Sp3     9
8  Group2     Sp4     8
```

Does anyone have the solution?
Thank you

What if I also have:

```
> tab
   Groups Species Value sp mrca
1  Group1     Sp1     1  3    3
2  Group1     Sp1     4  3    3
3  Group1     Sp2    78 NA   NA
4  Group1     Sp3    NA  3   12
5  Group1     Sp4    NA  3    3
6  Group2     Sp2     3  2    3
7  Group2     Sp3     9  2    40
8  Group2     Sp4     8 NA   NA
9  Group3     Sp1     9  2    2
10 Group3     Sp3    10  3    3
11 Group3     Sp3   110  3    2
12 Group3     Sp3    14  2    3
```

and I want to filter all groups that have < 80 Values and where the sp - mrca = 0:9

I tried wit your answer:

```
tab %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  filter(all(Value < 80 |is.na(Value))) %>%
  filter((all(abs(sp - mrca) %in% 0:9)|is.na(sp) & is.na(mrca)))
```

But it does not seem to be the right code

I should get :

```
> tab
   Groups Species Value sp mrca
1  Group1     Sp1     1  3    3
2  Group1     Sp1     4  3    3
3  Group1     Sp2    78 NA   NA
4  Group1     Sp3    NA  3   12
5  Group1     Sp4    NA  3    3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing NA observations with dplyr::filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857653/removing-na-observations-with-dplyrfilter)

Comment: ^ Not an exact dupe

Comment: Do you need `tab%>% group_by(Groups) %>% filter(all(Value < 80 |is.na(Value)), abs(sp - mrca) %in% 0:9)`

Comment: I don't understand why `Group2` is removed.  Your logic suggests that sp-mrca is also TRUE for those rows (if it is `abs` difference)`

Comment: @akrun `Group2` is removed because in the `row 7` `40- 2 = 38` and not between `0 and 9`

Comment: So you may need to wrap with `all` there too

Comment: Not clear based on the logic `tab %>% group_by(Groups) %>% mutate(ind = all(abs(sp - mrca) %in% 0:9))`

Comment: Okay, I think you changed the data again

Comment: This should work `tab1 %>% group_by(Groups) %>% filter(all(Value < 80 |is.na(Value))) %>% filter(all(na.omit(abs(sp-mrca)) %in% 0:9))`

Comment: @akrun yes perfect it works thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use and `|` with `is.na`

```
tab %>%
    group_by(Groups) %>%
    filter(all(Value < 80 |is.na(Value)))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   Groups [2]
#  Groups Species Value
#  <chr>  <chr>   <int>
#1 Group1 Sp1         1
#2 Group1 Sp1         4
#3 Group1 Sp2        78
#4 Group1 Sp3        NA
#5 Group1 Sp4        NA
#6 Group2 Sp2         3
#7 Group2 Sp3         9
#8 Group2 Sp4         8
```

---

The issue in OP's code was that when we wrap `all` with `Value < 80`, the comparison returns `NA` for those values that are `NA` and now the `all` also returns `NA` instead of a logical TRUE/FALSE and in `filter`, it automatically drops the `NA` by default

To understand better, check the output of

```
tab %>% 
    group_by(Groups) %>% 
    mutate(ind = all(Value < 80))
```

and the difference here

```
tab %>% 
    group_by(Groups) %>% 
    mutate(ind = all(Value < 80| is.na(Value)))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tab)[, .SD[all(Value < 80 | is.na(Value))], Groups]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
tab[with(tab, ave(Value < 80  | is.na(Value), Groups, FUN = all)),]
```

#### Update

For the second dataset,

```
tab1 %>% 
    group_by(Groups) %>%
    filter(all(Value < 80 |is.na(Value)),
           all(na.omit(abs(sp-mrca)) %in% 0:9))
```

#### data

```
tab <- structure(list(Groups = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
"Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", 
"Group3"), Species = c("Sp1", "Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp2", 
"Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp1", "Sp3", "Sp3", "Sp3"), Value = c(1L, 4L, 
78L, NA, NA, 3L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 110L, 14L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))



tab1 <- structure(list(Groups = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
"Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", 
"Group3"), Species = c("Sp1", "Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp2", 
"Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp1", "Sp3", "Sp3", "Sp3"), Value = c(1L, 4L, 
78L, NA, NA, 3L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 110L, 14L), sp = c(3L, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), mrca = c(3L, 3L, NA, 
12L, 3L, 3L, 40L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: Hello @akrun , with this solution only Group2 passes the filter and only NA values from the Group1 (not the 1, 4 and 78)

Comment: @chippycentra  Sorry, it is a `|` operator

Comment: I updated my post with another similar case if you have a time to take a look?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ave` from base R with `subset`. Remove `NA` rows from data and find groups which have `all` values less than 80 and `subset` it from original `tab`

```
subset(tab, Groups %in% unique(with(na.omit(tab), 
            Groups[ave(Value < 80, Groups, FUN = all)])))

#  Groups Species Value
#1 Group1     Sp1     1
#2 Group1     Sp1     4
#3 Group1     Sp2    78
#4 Group1     Sp3    NA
#5 Group1     Sp4    NA
#6 Group2     Sp2     3
#7 Group2     Sp3     9
#8 Group2     Sp4     8
```