# Does dplyr::filter using a logical variable ignore missing values?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am wondering how `dplyr::filter()` handles missing logical variables. Does filtering using a logical variable ignore missing values?

Consider this small example; say, we collect the heights of students in a classroom, but I am only interested in finding the mean height of the transfer students.

```
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
set.seed(2423)
#  options(pillar.print_min = Inf, pillar.print_max = Inf)
small_tibble <- tibble(height = c(rnorm(n = 5, 56, 10), rnorm(n = 10, 46, 10), rnorm(n = 15, 66, 10)),
                       transfer = c(rep(TRUE, 15), rep(FALSE, 15))
                       
                       
)
print(small_tibble, n = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 30 x 2
#>    height transfer
#>     <dbl> <lgl>   
#>  1   52.5 TRUE    
#>  2   59.9 TRUE    
#>  3   56.1 TRUE    
#>  4   50.5 TRUE    
#>  5   52.5 TRUE    
#>  6   53.1 TRUE    
#>  7   54.3 TRUE    
#>  8   40.7 TRUE    
#>  9   53.5 TRUE    
#> 10   49.3 TRUE    
#> 11   67.5 TRUE    
#> 12   53.3 TRUE    
#> 13   52.5 TRUE    
#> 14   25.7 TRUE    
#> 15   44.0 TRUE    
#> 16   70.9 FALSE   
#> 17   68.0 FALSE   
#> 18   59.2 FALSE   
#> 19   59.3 FALSE   
#> 20   64.9 FALSE   
#> 21   70.9 FALSE   
#> 22   63.3 FALSE   
#> 23   79.0 FALSE   
#> 24   69.4 FALSE   
#> 25   68.8 FALSE   
#> 26   76.0 FALSE   
#> 27   78.9 FALSE   
#> 28   62.4 FALSE   
#> 29   71.4 FALSE   
#> 30   77.2 FALSE

janitor::tabyl(small_tibble, transfer)
#>  transfer  n percent
#>     FALSE 15     0.5
#>      TRUE 15     0.5

#Mean height of all students
small_tibble %>%
  summarize(n(), mean(height))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   `n()` `mean(height)`
#>   <int>          <dbl>
#> 1    30           60.2

# Mean height of transfer students
small_tibble %>% 
  filter(transfer) %>% 
  summarize(n(), mean(height))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   `n()` `mean(height)`
#>   <int>          <dbl>
#> 1    15           51.0
```

Suppose now that we don't know that the first 5 students are transferred.

```
small_tibble$transfer[1:5] <- NA
    
 janitor::tabyl(small_tibble, transfer)
#>  transfer  n   percent valid_percent
#>     FALSE 15 0.5000000           0.6
#>      TRUE 10 0.3333333           0.4
#>        NA  5 0.1666667            NA
```

How does `filter` on a missing logical variable affects the mean of height?

Comment: This was asked and answered many times before.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857653/removing-na-observations-with-dplyrfilter

Comment: The above link talks about a different case. All variables in the tibble are numeric, not logical. The question is geared toward more about the behavior of `filter()` over removing missing values.

Answer (score 1):

When using `filter` on a logical variable, the function ignores `NA` values unless they are explicitly stated (i.e., `is.na()`). From the example,

```
    small_tibble %>% 
        filter(transfer) %>% 
        summarize(n(), mean(height))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   `n()` `mean(height)`
#>   <int>          <dbl>
#> 1    10           49.4
```

So filter ignores NA's unless they are explicitly stated, as follows.

```
    small_tibble %>% 
        filter(transfer | is.na(transfer)) %>%   #Here, I am explicitly asking `filter()` to include missing transfer status. 
        summarize(n(), mean(height))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   `n()` `mean(height)`
#>   <int>          <dbl>
#> 1    15           51.0
```

When explicitly stated, the height of the 5 missing transfer students and 10 known transfer students are included. The mean is the same as above.