# sum(is.na(df$x) gives me a different answer than dplyr df%>%filter(x==NA)

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` with variable `x`. However, two different expression to check on `NA` give me different results. Can anyone explain?

```
sum(is.na(df$x)
#[1] 41

df %>% filter(x==NA)
#A tibble: 0 x 1`
```

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this question will clear some things up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100974/na-matches-na-but-is-not-equal-to-na-why

Answer (score 0):

Note that a comparison with `NA` via `==`  (nearly) always evaluates to `NA`. This is easily demonstrated with:

```
x <- c(1, 2, NA, 4)
x == NA
#[1] NA NA NA NA
```

See `help("NA")` and `help("==")`. From the latter documentation:

> Missing values (`NA`) and `NaN` values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in `NA`.

So your `dplyr` code should be:

```
df %>% filter(is.na(x))
```