# Unexpected behavior with using %in% with NA

Tags: r, data-cleaning, na

When testing if a string is in another vector, I have been using `%in%` like this:

```
> "apple" %in% c("apple", "bannana")
[1] TRUE
```

```
> "carrot" %in% c("apple", "bannana")
[1] FALSE
```

However, when I input `NA`, it returns `TRUE` if there's another `NA` in the vector. I would have expected it to return `NA`. Is there another function I can use to get around this behavior?

```
> NA_character_ %in% c("apple", "bannana", NA_character_)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is to be expected since `NA_character_` is indeed *in* `c("apple", "bannana", NA_character_)`

Comment: `%in%` is defined as `match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0`. From `?match`: "For all types, `NA` matches `NA`". However, you can use the `incomparables` argument in `match`, `incomparables = NA`, to get your desired behaviour.

Comment: Somewhat related: [NA matches NA, but is not equal to NA. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100974/na-matches-na-but-is-not-equal-to-na-why)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any`:

```r
any(NA_character_ == c("apple", "bannana", NA_character_))
#[1] NA

any("apple" == c("apple", "bannana", NA))
#[1] TRUE
```